# How can I make NSObject that is created in runtime key value coding-compliant

Tags: ios, objective-c

First of all I want to point out that yes there are a lot of questions on this subject on stack overflow but none that was of any help. I also tried asking the owners of these for advice but was unable to get in touch with any of them.

Here is my scenario. I'm receiving data from an API which is an array of objects. These object are all the same structure but they change dynamically from API end point. When I made an NSArray of NSDictionary and tried to set my grid data source with the value of the provided array. It didn't work. When I looked at the documentation IGGridViewDataSourceHelper I found out the following piece of information "As of right now, the data must be of a derivation of NSObject and have at least one property". So I started thinking of a way to create an NSObject at run time. I was able to find some resource on Apple Developers documentation to make that.

Given that the variable dictionary is given in a function

Kindly check the following

```
- (NSArray *)getRecrodsFromDictionary: (NSDictionary*)dictionary {
    // the following include the array that I want to turn into objects
    NSArray * response = [self parseKey:@"responseDetails" fromDictionary:dictionary];
    NSMutableArray * rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if ([response count] != 0) {
        // 1. get all NSDictionary keys
        NSDictionary * temp = response[0];
        NSArray * keys = [temp allKeys];

        // 2. create a class
        Class ModelClass = objc_allocateClassPair([NSObject class], "WidgetDetailsModel", 0);

        // 3. all class variables with the same name as key retrieved from NSDictionary
        for (NSString * key in keys) {
            NSString * currkey = [key capitalizedString];
            const char * name = [currkey UTF8String];
            class_addIvar(ModelClass, name, sizeof(id), rint(log2(sizeof(id))), @encode(NSString));
        }

        // 4. register a class to be used
        objc_registerClassPair(ModelClass);

        for (NSDictionary * curr in response) {
            // create object
            id MC = [[ModelClass alloc] init];
            for (NSString * key in keys) {
                // set values
                const char * name = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                Ivar CurrVar = class_getInstanceVariable(ModelClass, name);
                NSString * newValue = [curr objectForKey: key];
                object_setIvar(MC, CurrVar, newValue);
            }
            // add object to array
            [rows addObject:MC];
        }
    }
    return [rows copy];
}
```

Once I get the return value and try to set it to data source data variable I get the following run time error.

[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key AssetsClass.

I can't find any thing on how to make the created in runtime NSObject key value coding-compliant. How can I make it key value coding-compliant?

Edit 1:
I managed to bypass the runtime error by making the fields names capitalized. 
Now the table is being populated with empty data (same number of rows as the data but empty text in it) which was the correct thing to happen because the values of the iVar is not retained. How Can I retain it?

Edit 2:
I'm still not able to retain the iVar value so I changed the location of the function to the same UIView class which then it did retain it for the short period of time I had to set the grid data source data value.
I'm curious to know if there is a way to make the iVar retained or set one of its attribute to be strong/retain to mark it for the deallocation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search on Google, StackOverFlow and other iOS related forums and research. Here is the conclusion that I was able to find. Ivar in objective-c will always be weak reference. In other words there is no way (that I can find) that makes the Ivar strong reference. This can only be achieved throw property with setting the attribute of each property made.